# Generating a PostgreSQL query that connects multiple tables and sums certain columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to get the following table returned via a PostgreSQL query:

```
container length | terminal 1 | terminal 2 | terminal 3 | Cumulative
----------------------------------------------------------------------
10               |   12       |     12     |     12     |     36     |
20               |   34       |     34     |     34     |     102    |
30               |   56       |     56     |     56     |     168    |
40               |   78       |     78     |     78     |     234    |
```

The numbers are made up but essentially I want to be able to see:

- the container length in the first column
- all my terminals with the respective number of containers for each container length
- the sum of those values (columns 2-4) for each row in column 4.

Is this possible via a SQL query?

The tables are as follows:

```
Organization
 - terminal_id
 - container_id

Container
 - organization_id
 - current_location_type
 - current_location_id

Terminal
 - organization_id
```

In other words, an Organization has many containers and has many terminals. A Terminal belongs to an organization. A Container belongs to an organization.

The way in which I can derive a terminal from a container is: `containers.current_location_type = 'Terminal'` and `containers.current_location_id = terminals.id`

I have the following SQL query but it's not returning the data in the way that I am looking to return it in the table above.

```
SELECT containers.container_length AS container_length,
  terminals.name AS terminal_name,
  COUNT(*) AS group_count
FROM containers
LEFT JOIN terminals
  ON terminals.organization_id = organization.id
  AND terminals.id = containers.current_location_id
WHERE containers.organization_id = organization.id
  AND containers.current_location_type = 'Terminal'
GROUP BY containers.container_length, terminals.id
ORDER BY container_length ASC
```

This query returns 3 columns: `container_length`, `terminal_name` and `group_count`. Seems like I'm on the right path but I haven't been able to find a way to get it as in the table above. Any thoughts on how I might achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to install extensions? If so you could use `crosstab` to pivot your results. This answer has examples: [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/3591528).

Comment: Do you have always 3 terminal columns or is the number flexible

Comment: @S-Man it's flexible and is determined by the organization's terminals

Comment: Hm I believe there's no simple solution for flexible columns. You can go with @teppic solution but it needs a fixed number of count columns (with FILTER). As well it is with the crosstab function where you need to name all used columns IMO. You need to do preparing step to calculate your columns. E.g. there's a way to build a query string dynamically in your calling system (or in postgres but it is quiet hard) and call it within a function which converts the string into a query.

Comment: Another possibility is reporting the terminal counts in JSON. The typing requirements are looser so you wouldn't need to know which terminals you're reporting for in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since 9.4 postgres has had the ability to apply aggregates selectively with `FILTER` clauses.

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT
  containers.container_length,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE terminals.name = 'terminal_1') AS terminal_1,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE terminals.name = 'terminal_2') AS terminal_2,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE terminals.name = 'terminal_3') AS terminal_3,
  count(*) AS cumulative
FROM containers -- ...
```

You'll have to adjust your grouping to only be by `container_length`.